# bluetooth connection error between raspberry pi compute module and blend micro

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

In a project I have a raspberry pi compute module and a blend micro, and I need to build a bluetooth low energy connection between these two devices. Since there is no built-in bluetooth in the compute module, I bought a bluetooth usb dongle ([http://www.amazon.com/Inateck-Bluetooth-Wireless-Compatible-Playback/dp/B00N2E3ZHG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448333914&sr=8-1&keywords=B00N2E3ZHG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00N2E3ZHG)), installed the latest bluez (version 5.34) and tried to use `gatttool` to connect the pi with the blend micro.

I have a problem making this connection. When I did `sudo hcitool lescan`, I can see the MAC address of the blend micro in the list of visible BLE devices, but when I did `sudo gatttool -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -t random -I --interactive`, and type `connect` in the interactive command line `[xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx][LE] > connect`, I get the following error message:

```
Error: connect: Connection refused (111)
```

I have verified that my bluetooth dongle is up running (I have done `sudo ~/PATH_TO_BLUEZ/tools/hciconfig hci0 up`), and that the MAC address I typed in the gatttool command is indeed the blend micro MAC address. I have also verified that the blend micro is working properly, because I can use the iOS app to connect to the blend micro and send data.

I have tried a bunch of methods to solve the problem without success... I first tried several versions of bluez, including version 5.11, and repeated the exact same procedure as above -- did not work. I then installed `blueman`, which is a GUI for bluetooth on Debian (the linux system running in the pi compute module), but it could not even find blend micro, while `sudo hcitool lescan` can find it. I have also tried to connect the raspberry pi with my laptop (OS X running El Capitan, in the system description it says the bluetooth supports BLE 4.0). My laptop can find raspberry pi, but could not connect to it. I suspect that the problem might be with the bluetooth dongle that I connect to the raspberry pi?

I feel I am running out of ideas now... Any suggestions that might resolve the connection issue would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here are some more details about the OS and the system that runs on my raspberry pi compute module:

(return value of `usb_release -a`)

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:        7.8
Codename:       wheezy
```

(return value of `name -r`)

```
4.1.7+
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this post!! Also please let me know if more info is needed... This is my first time posting anything here...

Comment: Could you use `bluetoothctl` -> `scan on` -> `connect <mac address>` and post the output of that? `hcitool` and `gatttool` are very old tools and I advise you not to use them. Can you also post the output of `btmon` (run in separate window) when you are trying to connect using `hcitool` and `gatttool`?

Comment: @Zimano output of `scan on` is `No default controller available`, and `connect <mac address>` is `Device <mac address> not available`

Comment: Could you check if the adapter is powered by using `bluetoothctl` -> `power on` and try again? Please also post the output of `hciconfig -a`. I do hope you realize that `<mac address> had to be replaced by a real bluetooth mac address, right! :)

Comment: @Zimano Hey I figured it out! It turned out the problem is that I have the improper linux kernel. Bluez works with kernel version 3.12.36. After I downgrade the system to this kernel version, it connects!

Comment: Great to hear you figured it out! Good luck!